# view of 2 tables with same column name but ids are different

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in MySQL t1 and t2. Both have same column names. Table t1 has huge data and t2 is not so huge as compared to t1 but in mean time t2 would also be of the same size as t1. The only difference is that the id column do not match in both the tables. I want to create a view out of these column.

What I have created is

```
CREATE VIEW vw_t1t2 AS  SELECT id , name , lastname, depid FROM t1
Union
SELECT  id , name , lastname, depid FROM t2;
```

If I do a query "Select * from vw_t1t2 where depid='100287'".

The view does not fetch the correct data, the data is mixture on all the records when I search for particular department id, some records are of different department id. Also it took 200 sec to execute the query.

Comment: So you want to create a view ONLY where the id fields are the same on each table?  Just trying to understand exactly what the end-game is here.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The view is not fetching the data the data is mixture on all the records when I search for particular department id.

Comment: For the query optimization could you execute and post here the result of the query: `EXPLAIN SELECT id, name, ...`

Comment: Igor it has 212 records, do you want me to post the data?

Answer (score 0):

you may consider to wrap the result of the union

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT id , name , lastname, depid FROM t1
   Union
   SELECT  id , name , lastname, depid FROM t2
) as sel1
WHERE depid = 2
```

but let us see the `EXPLAIN` output to optimize the query